# Sddm login screen blank but active

Tags: login, kde, plasma, sddm

I'm using KDE plasma with lightdm. I can boot my laptop without any problems. However, I can't change my login screen this way.

So, my question is: Why am I getting a black screen at the login if I choose Sddm as the display manager? If I write my password blindly, it'll login correctly. And if I choose Lightdm instead of Sddm, it will boot correctly.

I'd really want to have Sddm; because there are very nice login screen themes in the system settings. So if there is a way to load Sddm without crushing anything, please lead the way.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
```

This didn't work.
Waiting for your reply,
Thank you.

Comment: What video card are you using? Are you  using X11 or Wayland?  Does KDE give you any problems after logging in?

Comment: I'm so sorry for this. The answer is not needed anymore; because I installed Kubuntu 20.10 now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Same issue here. What caused my issue was messing around with the wallpapers, then desktop crashed. Black screen with just cursor when logging in with sddm but when choosing gdm3 login works again and desktop appears to work.